# AsyncWriteExt does not write all bytes Rust TcpStream

Tags: rust, tcp, rust-tokio

I am implementing a TCP server to pass messages.

From the `tokio-yamux` library I can share this tcp connection with different channels. This library only allows me to use the `AsyncWriteExt` and `AsyncReadExt` methods to write and read bytes. This is not a problem as it suits my needs.

The problem comes when I send a whole message and bytes are missing in it, so a global block happens in the application. The client sends X bytes, before being sent by tcp a header with the length of these is added. In this way the server can know firmly the bytes to be read.

For this reason, when I write bytes in this case 262144, only 262136 are written with the `write_all` or `write` method. Then as in the header it is indicated that in total there are 262144 it is blocked because there are still bytes to read.

I don't understand why this happens.

Little example:
Client:

```
use futures::prelude::*;
use std::{error::Error, vec};
use tokio::{
    io::{AsyncReadExt, AsyncWriteExt},
    net::TcpStream,
};
use tokio_yamux::{config::Config, session::Session};

#[tokio::main]
pub async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let socket = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:8080").await?;
    println!("[client] connected to server: {:?}", socket.peer_addr()?);
    println!("created stream");

    let mut session = Session::new_client(socket, Config::default());
    let ctrl = session.control();

    let mut handles = Vec::new();

    tokio::spawn(async move {
        loop {
            match session.next().await {
                Some(Ok(_)) => (),
                Some(Err(e)) => {
                    println!("{}", e);
                    break;
                }
                None => {
                    println!("closed");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    for _i in 0..1 {
        let mut ctrl_clone = ctrl.clone();
        handles.push(tokio::spawn(async move {
            match ctrl_clone.open_stream().await {
                Ok(mut stream) => {


                    // This sections represents Check User Operation
                    // Args -> operation_id = I selected a random i32
                    //      -> queue_id = queue to write

                    // Writes to the server to identify the operation and get the queue
                    let operation_id = 0;
                    let queue_id = Some(2);

                    let data_to_send;

                    match queue_id {
                        Some(id) => {
                            data_to_send = vec![operation_id, id];
                        }
                        None => {
                            data_to_send = vec![operation_id];
                        }
                    }

                    let data_to_send: Vec<u8> = data_to_send
                        .clone()
                        .into_iter()
                        .flat_map(|x| i32::to_be_bytes(x))
                        .collect();

                    stream.write_all(&data_to_send).await.unwrap();
                    stream.flush().await.unwrap();

                    let sv_code: i32;
                    let mut buf = [1; 4];

                    // Reads from server to recieve an ACCEPTED MESSAGE
                    loop {
                        //stream.readable().await.unwrap();

                        match stream.read_exact(&mut buf).await {
                            Ok(0) => {}
                            Ok(n) => {
                                println!("Client: Reading Buffer: n_bytes {:?}", n);
                                sv_code = i32::from_be_bytes(buf);
                                break;
                            }
                            Err(ref e) if e.kind() == std::io::ErrorKind::WouldBlock => {
                                //println!("Err: TCP -> SV (Write))");
                                continue;
                            }
                            Err(_e) => {
                                //return Err(e.into());
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // Here I return a code to client just to Continue with the execution and start Sending messages
                    // Skipped

                    // This section represents SEND Operation
                    // Header 

                    let data: [u8; 262140] = [1; 262140];

                    let mut vec_data = data.to_vec();
                    
                    let len = data.len() as u32;
                    let len_slices = len.to_be_bytes();

                    for slice in len_slices {
                        vec_data.insert(0, slice);
                    }

                    println!("Total_len: {:?}", vec_data.len());
                    let n = stream.write_all(&vec_data).await.unwrap();
                    println!("N: {:?}", n);
                    stream.flush().await.unwrap();

                    println!("Fin write");
                }
                Err(e) => {
                    println!("{:?}", e);
                }
            }
        }));
    }

    for handle in handles {
        let _ = handle.await;
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Server:

```
use tokio::io::{AsyncReadExt, AsyncWriteExt};
use tokio::net::TcpListener;

use std::error::Error;

use futures::prelude::*;
use tokio_yamux::{config::Config, session::Session};

// https://github.com/nervosnetwork/tentacle

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let addr = "127.0.0.1:8080".to_string();

    let listener = TcpListener::bind(&addr).await.unwrap();

    while let Ok((socket, _)) = listener.accept().await {
        println!("accepted a socket: {:?}", socket.peer_addr());
        let mut session = Session::new_server(socket, Config::default());
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            while let Some(Ok(mut stream)) = session.next().await {
                println!("Server accept a stream from client: id={}", stream.id());
                tokio::spawn(async move {
                    let mut buffer = Vec::<u8>::with_capacity(8);
                    
                    // Identify operation from Client
                    let op_code = stream.read_i32().await.unwrap();

                    println!("op_id: {:?}", op_code);

                    let queue_id = Some(stream.read_i32().await.unwrap());

                    println!("queue_id: {:?}", queue_id);

                    // Here I write to client -> Accepted
                    let mut sv_code: i32 = 0;
                    stream.write_all(&sv_code.to_be_bytes()).await.unwrap();
                    stream.flush().await.unwrap();

                    // Starting receiving messages
                    let mut total_bytes = 0;
                    let mut n_bytes_read = 0;

                    let mut chunk_id = 0;
                    let mut last_chunk = false;
                    let mut len_slices: [u8; 4] = [0; 4];
                    loop {

                        println!("n_bytes read: {:?}", n_bytes_read);

                        let mut capacity = 65535;
                
                        if n_bytes_read == 0 {
                            capacity = 65539;
                        }
                
                        let mut buffer = Vec::<u8>::with_capacity(capacity);
                                
                        println!("Blocked?");
                        match stream.read_buf(&mut buffer).await {
                            Ok(0) => continue,
                            Ok(n) => {
                                println!("N: {:?}", n);
                                if n_bytes_read == 0 {
                                    for i in 0..4 {
                                        len_slices[i] = buffer.remove(0);
                                    }
                                    total_bytes = u32::from_le_bytes(len_slices);
                                    total_bytes += 4;
                                }
                
                                buffer.truncate(n);
                
                                n_bytes_read += n;
                
                                if n_bytes_read == total_bytes.try_into().unwrap() {
                                    last_chunk = true;
                                }
                
                                chunk_id += 1;
                
                                if last_chunk {
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            Err(ref e) if e.kind() == std::io::ErrorKind::WouldBlock => {
                                println!("Err: TCP -> SV (Write))");
                                continue;
                            }
                            Err(e) => {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    println!("Finished");

                });
            }
        });
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

And the output:

Client:

```
[client] connected to server: 127.0.0.1:8080
created stream
Client: Reading Buffer: n_bytes 4
Total_len: 262144
Blocked here
```

Server:

```
accepted a socket: Ok(127.0.0.1:52430)
Server accept a stream from client: id=1
n_bytes read: 0
Blocked?
N: 65539
n_bytes read: 65539
Blocked?
N: 65535
n_bytes read: 131074
Blocked?
N: 65535
n_bytes read: 196609
Blocked?
N: 65527
n_bytes read: 262136
Blocked?
```

Comment: `write()` may indeed not write all bytes. `write_all()` should. You said you've tested with both, so please replace the `write()` with `write_all()`. Also, please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I created a little example and works perfectly... I don't understand why in my real code doesn't. I use write.flush() every time I write. I will add the little example...

Comment: If it works perfectly, it doesn't help us. It is great that you've found this, since that means the issue is not within the code you showed us. So now take your time and try to strip more and more parts of your program until you will find the _minimal_ program that also has the same problem. After that, you can post it here. And who knows, maybe you'll even find the answer by your own along the way! (In this case, make sure to post a self-answer here).

Comment: By adding a few more steps in the example I was able to reproduce the error! There is an exchange of messages to indicate the type of operation and to receive the acceptance message between the client and the server. These include more back end computation but it has nothing to do with the problem. If you run the example you can see how the same problem I raise in the question occurs. I just edited the example.

Comment: It worked by luck, but note that your first usage of `read_buf()` in the server code is incorrect. It may as well read less. You need [`read_exact()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/io/trait.AsyncReadExt.html#method.read_exact), or better, two [`read_i32()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/io/trait.AsyncReadExt.html#method.read_i32).

Comment: Why are you truncating the buffer after every `read()`?

Comment: I have made the modifications that you have commented me on the first read and it continues with the same error. The first truncate no longer exists, it is not necessary. The second one is done in case the read() does not fill the entire buffer, trim it so as not to send half an empty buffer.

Comment: `read_buf()` will take care for that, it will not advance the position further than actually read.

Comment: I have tried to send the header before with a write.i32() and a read.i32() and thus not to put it inside the byte vector. I still have the same problem. I have found that removing bytes, instead of sending 262,140 and sending 100,000 everything works perfectly. Maybe it runs out of memory, or there is a byte limit with write all or some similar problem?
Edit: This may be true. I sent a 300.000 bytes and it only reads 262232. We may have found a limit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in the Multiplexer Configuration. Here you can see: [tokio_yamux::config::Config](https://docs.rs/tokio-yamux/latest/tokio_yamux/config/struct.Config.html#structfield.max_stream_window_size), the `Config::default()` allows a maximum window number of 262144 bytes. This was exceeded within this example, therefore the stream it created over the TcpStream reached the set limit. If a new configuration is created increasing the value of `max_stream_window_size` this error does not happen anymore.

Solution:

```
let config = Config {
        accept_backlog: 256,
        enable_keepalive: true,
        keepalive_interval: Duration::from_secs(30),
        connection_write_timeout: Duration::from_secs(10),
        max_stream_count: 65535,
        max_stream_window_size: 4294967295,
    };

let mut session = Session::new_server(socket, config);
```

Comment: I appreciate that you got it working, and gave you an upvote; but is there a way to solve it without kicking the Y2K can down the road? Can you guarantee your messages will never exceed this new maximum?